# Videos crashing computer

Tags: youtube-api

Videos with the yellow mark continue to crash at that yellow mark. Here's an example.

http://youtu.be/1U5uheub2mo

That will crash my computer each time at 10 seconds when it reaches that yellow 10 second mark.

I tried playing other videos that didn't happen to have the crash marker, and they play all the way through.

I found a different one with the same yellow marker at 10 seconds and the different video crashed.

Comment: The answer to @Daniel Ruf's question ishere: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081210090327AAWbnGh

Comment: maybe something tries to block the advertisements and causes the crash?

Answer (score 1):

You should turn Html5 ON, probably it stops from crashing.
Enter here http://www.youtube.com/html5

And click on "Join Html5 Test" something like this.

Then when you see a video, the html5 function automatically will do the trick instead of using adobe flash player.

Ps: it don't work to ALL of videos, some videos don't have the html5 option, that will be played with adobe flash player instead.